# JQuery on Clicks add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello people** I've created a simple cars animations but there are many problems that when the user clicks on the more than button in the same time, this problem in the video will appears so How to prevent this problem, The reason is that we will not be able to predict what the user will do

[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPSf13ABEH4)

**Here my code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $cars = $('.car');
    var temp = 1;
    $('.car-model').on('click', function () {
        /*=========================
         * Add Class Active
         */
        $(this).addClass('activeModel').parent().siblings().find('.car-model').removeClass('activeModel');
        var index = $(this).data('index');
        if (temp == index) {

        } else {
            var $current = $cars.find('.current');
            var $next = $('[data-car-index="' + index + '"]').parent();
            $current.addClass('car--trans-out');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.car-image-container').removeClass('whelrotateClick');
                $current.removeClass('current').removeClass('car--trans-out');
                $next.addClass('current').addClass('car--trans-in');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $next.removeClass('car--trans-in');
                }, 1000)
            }, 1000);
        }
        temp = index;
    });
    $('.selectContainer').on('change', function () {
        var index = $(this).find('option:selected').data('index');
        var $current = $cars.find('.current');
        var $next = $('[data-car-index="' + index + '"]').parent();

        $current.addClass('car--trans-out');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $current.removeClass('current').removeClass('car--trans-out');
            $next.addClass('current').addClass('car--trans-in');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $next.removeClass('car--trans-in');
            }, 1000)
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

```css
.car{
    padding:40px 0;
}
.car .changeCarSelect{
    display:none;
    text-align:left;
}
.car .changeCarSelect span{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:4px;
    font-size:14px;
}
.car .selectContainer {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border:1px solid rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.89);
    outline:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.car .car-button .car-model{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.car .car-button .car-model h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Raleway", Arial, Tahoma;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.car .car-button .car-model.activeModel h3{
    background-color:#333;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.car div[class^='col']{
    padding:4px;
}
.car .car-relative{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.car-image-container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.car .car-image{
    display: none;
}
.car .car-image img{
    margin:auto;
}
.car .current{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
.car .current .car-image{
    display: block;
}
.car--trans-in .car-image {
    -moz-animation: trans-in 1s ease-out;
    -o-animation: trans-in 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: trans-in 1s ease-out;
    animation: trans-in 1s ease-out;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    -o-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
.car--trans-out .car-image {
    -moz-animation: trans-out 1s ease-in;
    -o-animation: trans-out 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-animation: trans-out 1s ease-in;
    animation: trans-out 1s ease-in;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22);
    -o-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22);
}
@-moz-keyframes trans-in {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(150%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(150%);
        -o-transform: translateX(150%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(150%);
        transform: translateX(150%);
    }
    80% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes trans-in {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(150%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(150%);
        -o-transform: translateX(150%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(150%);
        transform: translateX(150%);
    }
    80% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@keyframes trans-in {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(150%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(150%);
        -o-transform: translateX(150%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(150%);
        transform: translateX(150%);
    }
    80% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes trans-out {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    10% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    80% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes trans-out {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    10% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    80% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
@keyframes trans-out {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    10% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    80% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)  {
    .car .changeCarSelect{
        display:block;
    }
    .car .car-button .car-model {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="car">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="changeCarSelect">
                <span>Change Car</span>
                <select class="selectContainer">
                    <option class="selectCar" data-index="1">
                        Car model
                    </option>
                    <option class="selectCar" data-index="2">
                        Car model
                    </option>
                    <option class="selectCar" data-index="3">
                        Car model
                    </option>
                    <option class="selectCar" data-index="4">
                        Car model
                    </option>
                    <option class="selectCar" data-index="5">
                        Car model
                    </option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="car-button">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="car-model activeModel" data-index="1">
                                    <h3>Car Model 1</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="car-model" data-index="2">
                                    <h3>Car Model 2</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="car-model" data-index="3">
                                    <h3>Car Model 3</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="car-model" data-index="4">
                                    <h3>Car Model 4</h3>
                                </div>
                                 </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="car-model" data-index="5">
                                    <h3>Car Model 5</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="car-relative">
                        <div class="car-image-container current">
                            <div class="car-image" data-car-index="1">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/149089668025111.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="car-image-container">
                            <div class="car-image" data-car-index="2">                                
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/149089668036292.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="car-image-container">
                            <div class="car-image" data-car-index="3">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/149089668053093.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="car-image-container">
                            <div class="car-image" data-car-index="4">                                
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/149089668064654.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="car-image-container">
                            <div class="car-image" data-car-index="5">                                
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/149089668081245.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Please run code snippet in fullscreen**

Answer (score 2):

If you animate using CSS3 than you can check for a **transition** is finished using:

```
// if you use CSS3 transition
$("selector").on("transitionend", function(){
   // do something ... like make buttons clickable again...
});
```

or if you use CSS3 **animation**

```
$("selector").on("animationend", function(){
   // do something
});
```

**EXAMPLE**

here's an example on how to use `.one()` and `.off()` jQuery's methods:

> as you can see, the button is not clickable while the car animates

```js
var $btn = $(".btn");
var $car = $(".car");

function initStates() {
  // Make button clickable
  $btn.one("click", moveCar);
  // Remove the animation class
  $car.removeClass("moveCar");
}

function moveCar() {
  console.log("BUTTON CLICK!!");

  // Remove Click handler
  $btn.off("click");

  // Move car using CSS3 animation
  // and call initStates on animationend (event callback)
  $car.addClass("moveCar").one("animationend", initStates);
}

// INITIALIZE default states
initStates();
```

```css
.car {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.moveCar /* CLASS ADDED BY JQUERY */ {
  animation: move 2s ease-out;
  background: green;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn">CLICK TO MOVE CAR</button>
<div class="car"></div>
```

If you use jQuery's `.animate()` than you can check if an item is animated using

```
if( $("selector").is(":animated") ) return;
// If a selector is animated the code below will not execute
alert("Animate next car!");
```

than, eventually, in order to memorize the clicked button while one car was animated - you could create a variable to store the value of the car to animate next once the current animated one triggers an `.animate` callback - Than remember to reset / null the variable after you've used it.

If instead - you **want** actually to have multiple cars running on screen - than you need to position your cars using

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me but could you give me an example and use my code, I tried to use It but it's not work.

Comment: @MohamedHassn I cannot really help because I don't know the desired needed behavior.

Comment: @MohamedHassn I'll create soon a really small demo just for example. Stay tuned

Comment: Thank you very much If you can create a really demo on my example that I can understand the techniques

Comment: @MohamedHassn see my demo. SHould give you a really clear insight on how to modify your code. Feel free to ask is something is unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood the idea somewhat but could you give an example of my code please?

Comment: please could you edit my code that The problem still exists